# Compiling C++ code to static library (.a)

Tags: c++, swift

So i asked some questions before regarding this, but i think i am finally getting closer to my goal of using a C++ Library in a Swift iOS Project. I have downloaded a C++ Library as tar.gz. To use this library i am supposed to install it on my computer using make, but i want it as a a static library (.a to my knowledge) to use it in a Swift App. I know how to use C++ in a Swift project thats working and running. But i can't find any helpful advice on how to compile this source to a static Library. You can download the Library [here](http://www.ginac.de/CLN/). I just need it in a .a file and don't really know how to start. Everything i am finding is using headers and things i absolutely do not know. 
Please excuse my confusion, I am an absolute newbie in C++.

Thanks a lot for future advice =)

And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckDXg.png) is the structure of the archive.

Comment: Use `make` as you suggest (in the top level directory). That usually outputs both dynamic and static library files. Look where the output is, and see if you get what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Now I have done , as the documentation of CLN said,  ./configure and then make and make check. But now i can not find my output =(

Comment: Try to write `find . -type f | grep "\.a$"` in the terminal when you're in the same folder. You can also try with `.d`, or `.so`.

Comment: Thank you very much again ! I did that in the same folder and it found my library libcln.a but in a Folder that does not seem to be existent :o

Comment: Heres the output cln-1.3.4 Jonas$ find . -type f | grep "\.a$"
./src/.libs/libcln.a

Comment: Look ate the structure i posted in my question. The folders did not change and i do not have a libs folder :o

Comment: There's a dot in the directory path, `.libs` which makes the finder hide it. It's still a perfectly valid path from the point of view of the OS though. You should be able to use this path (to get the absolute path, write `pwd` and add the `/src/.libs/libcln.a` after) by linking to it in Xcode, or whatever IDE/compiler you use.

Comment: Awesome ! Now I got it ! Thanks for you patience and the great advice !

Comment: I added an answer which outlined the points. If it worked for you, you can accept it so the next person has an easier way to find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile the code and link it with your compiler. Suggested steps:

1. Run `make` in the top-most folder of the source code
2. Find the location of the library file by running `find . -type f | grep "\.a$"` in the terminal.
3. Add the path to the library file in your IDE or compiler.

Comment: Thanks for your great help ! That solved my problem ! Made my day =)